# Magento checkout - Address option

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

At magento checkout, when the user has already got registered address, it comes with a `select` to choose between the registered address or choose a new address.

How would I change this so that when the checkout was loaded, regardless of whether the client has a registered address or not, the "new address" was checked and the fields opened for typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by making it possible for only the user to register a new address and not being able to select what he registered the following way:

In the app \ design \ frontend \ YourPackage \ YourTheme \ template \ checkout \ onepage \ billing.phtml file comment the following code:

```
<div class="input-box">
   <?php //echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
</div>
```

A little further down, in the `ul`, comment the `display: none` so that the fields already appear in the page load.

**Original Code:**

```
<ul id="onestepcheckout-billing-address-list"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="overflow: hidden;height: 0px;display:none"<?php endif; ?>>
```

**Code changed:**

```
<ul id="onestepcheckout-billing-address-list"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="overflow: hidden;height: 100%;/*display:none*/"<?php endif; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `->setValue('your value')` to your select generation. You can set here option `New Address`.

Comment: This code returns me error 500 on the console.

Comment: show me your code

Comment: I use the code that is in billing.phtml

Comment: please copy your code (where select is generated) and paste here

Comment: From this code that is located in the file billing.phtml, the magento "mounts" the `select` where you have the option to choose the address already registered, or choose to send in a new address: `<label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a shipping address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label><div class="input-box"><?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes in your billing.phtml file located here

app\design\frontend\YourPackage\YourTheme\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

**Your Default Code:**

```
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li id="billing-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();?>
                <?php (empty($addressId)) ? $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId(0) : '' ?>
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li id="billing-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses() && !empty($addressId)): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />
```

Make same changes for the Shipping address on checkout page

app\design\frontend\YourPackage\YourTheme\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml

Comment: It did not work with your code.